# Running Celery tasks for 2 Django applications within a same project?

Tags: django, celery

I have a Django project which requires Celery tasks to run for two of its apps. I was wondering if there was a way to have a single celery.py file which runs both of them.

File tree:

```
src
|--api 
|      |-- init.py
|      |-- otherFiles
|      |-- celery 
|          |-- celery.py
| 
|--xyz 
|      |-- init.py
|      |-- otherFiles
|      |-- celery 
|         |-- celery.py
|
|--otherApps
```

If I were to run to Celery apps manually, I would run:

```
source venv/bin/activate
cd src
celery worker -A api
```

And in another terminal:

```
source venv/bin/activate
cd src
celery worker -A xyz
```

The two celery workers require access to the same databases.

This is how my celery file looks like:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "api.settings")
app = Celery("api")
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

The other replaces `app = Celery('api')` with `app = Celery('xyz')`.

Is this the correct way to handle this? Can I create a single script and run both tasks from it?

If not, what's the best way to daemonize this?

Production server is running Ubuntu 18.04 and python 3.6.9, so I'm planning on using systemd although suggestions are welcome too.

Comment: Here is good article about that: https://medium.com/@channeng/celery-scheduler-part-2-managing-celery-with-supervisor-2a0c6e7f7a6e

Comment: @MikołajRutecki Supervisor requires me to install version 3.3.1 which is not compatible with Python 3. Would you know why that is or how to go around it? The entire django project is written with Python 3 so using Python 2 is really not an option.

Comment: Version 4.1.0 of Supervisor should do the job.

Comment: @MikołajRutecki It's weird, even though I have v 4.1.0, it throws the following error: `The 'supervisor==3.3.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application`.

Comment: Try this instead https://riptutorial.com/django/example/32120/celery-plus-rabbitmq-with-supervisor

Comment: @MikołajRutecki The first link you supplied was very helpful. It's working now. I still have an issue with Redis showing "Address already in use" in the redis.log file, but that's really not that big of a problem. The production server's routing traffic as intended. Thank you :)